# Multiple select against one table in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, multiple-select

I'm trying to construct a select statement that will give me a percentage value for each month and user.

I have a table with rows that looks like this;
Table name: pytrans

```
tTransDate  tArtCode  tTime  tSignature
20120801    DKK       1      30JK
20120801    AD        1.5    30JK
20120802    DKB       3      40AK
20120903    MI        2      45TR
20120904    DKK       2      30JK
20120904    DKB       2      30JK
```

The select(s) should give me the percentage of how much time spent on tArtCode DKB or DKK for each signature and month of all time spent on all tArtCode. So from the above example the select should give me 40% for signature 30JK in month 8 and 100% for signature 30JK in month 9.

I have tried different kind of sql select statements but It doesn’t seem to get 100% right.
This is what I’ve got;

```
select DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) AS Month, tSignatur,
   (select SUM(tAntal) AS SumPart from pytrans where tSignatur = '30JK' AND (tArtikelkod = 'DKK' OR tArtikelkod = 'DKB'))
    /(select DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) AS Month, SUM(tAntal) AS SumTot from pytrans where tSignatur = '30JK' GROUP BY Year, Month, SumTot) * 100
From pytrans where tSignatur = '30JK' GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum), DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum), tSignatur
```

This SQL don’t work the error is that I can’t group Year, Month, SumTot. Also i get error; Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

This next sql select give me what i want but I’m to specific what I’m asking for... so to speak. If I use this sql i then need to have a sql query for every signature and every month, and that’s not really creative.

```
select TOP 1 DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) AS Month, tSignatur, 
SumProc = (select SUM(tAntal) from pytrans
          where tSignatur = '30JK' AND (tArtikelkod NOT LIKE 'FL' AND tArtikelkod NOT LIKE 'SEM' AND tArtikelkod NOT LIKE 'KOMPIN') AND (tArtikelkod = 'DKK' OR tArtikelkod = 'DKB') AND tTransdatum BETWEEN '20121101' AND '20121131')
          / (select SUM(tAntal) from pytrans 
          where tSignatur = '30JK' AND (tArtikelkod NOT LIKE 'FL' AND tArtikelkod NOT LIKE 'SEM' AND tArtikelkod NOT LIKE 'KOMPIN') AND tTransdatum BETWEEN '20121101' AND '20121131') * 100
from pytrans
Where tSignatur = '30JK' AND tTransdatum BETWEEN '20121101' AND '20121131'
group by tTransdatum, tSignatur
```

I’ve also tried Union but that doesn’t seem to work for me.

I really need help with this! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us _exactly_ what the expected output is, given the current example data?  Also, what's up with prefixing everything with `'t'`?  Don't abbreviate things unless absolutely necessary, and would be well understood - does `trans` stand for 'transaction', 'transfer', or something else?  Don't label columns with their types, make the type obvious from the name - ie, use `occurredOn` instead of `tTransDate`.  Don't use `BETWEEN`, always use an exclusive upper bound (`'<'`), _especially_ with date/time/timestamps.  If you give us examples, at least make sure all names match...

Comment: I'm not the creator of this database and I don’t really know why it's prefixed with “t”. Trans stands for transaction in this database, or to be more precise “time transaction”. The column name is also something I’m wondering about but nothing I can change.
I'm curious about why not to use BETWEEN isn’t it as precise as < ? I’m using BETWEEN in a various kind of scenarios just when it comes to date.

Comment: In _most_ RDBMSs, `BETWEEN` is actually an inclusive upper bound (`'<='`).  This makes dealing with ranges awkward, and promotes off-by-one errors, especially considering date/time/timestamp types, even more so on SQL Server.  One of the other responders on this site, Aaron Bertrand, has a good [blog entry](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on the perils there.  But really, it usually is the result of conceptualizing what your data actually means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create Table #pytrans(tTransdatum datetime,  tArtCode varchar(10), tAntal float,  tSignature varchar(10))

insert into #pytrans Values('20120801',    'DKK',       1      ,'30JK')
insert into #pytrans Values('20120801',    'AD',        1.5    ,'30JK')
insert into #pytrans Values('20120802',    'DKB',       3      ,'40AK')
insert into #pytrans Values('20120903',    'MI',        2      ,'45TR')
insert into #pytrans Values('20120904',    'DKK',       2      ,'30JK')
insert into #pytrans Values('20120904',    'DKB',       2      ,'30JK')

Select a.Year,a.Month,a.tSignature,a.SumPart as aAll,b.SumPart as bAll,Case when b.SumPart =0 then NULL else a.SumPart/b.SumPart * 100 end as [Percent]
 from
(select DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) AS Month, tSignature
,SUM(tAntal) AS SumPart
from #pytrans
where tSignature = '30JK' AND tArtCode in( 'DKK' ,'DKB')
Group by DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) , DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) , tSignature) a
Left Join
(select DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) AS Month, tSignature
,SUM(tAntal) AS SumPart
from #pytrans
where tSignature = '30JK' 
Group by DATEPART(YY, tTransdatum) , DATEPART(mm, tTransdatum) , tSignature) b
on a.Month=b.Month and a.Year =b.Year and a.tSignature = b.tSignature
```

Comment: Thank you bummi it gave me exactly what I was looking for and i would newer been able to put that freaking assume sql together my self!